# Extend div height within a div of uncertain height

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to extend the height of div within a div that doesn't have a fixed height. I have to do this without using `position:absolute` because the extended div needs to interact with other divs.

The extended div can't have a fixed height and neither the div it's in...

Is there a way to do this in CSS without using JS?

http://jsfiddle.net/q3Sze/2/

**Update:**

To clarify, in the example, I'm trying to extend the height of `.extend` div from top to bottom of the `.main` div. `.extend` should not have a fixed height and should not be position `absolute` because it needs to push elements that's around it. To make things even more complicated, the divs are for a fluid site so everything except the `.extend` div must have a width of 100%.

If you specify a height for `.extend` you will see what I'm trying to achieve but need to do it without a height specified.

Comment: What's your objective here? Not quite clear from the example/code alone

Comment: You have two divs next to each other... Do you them to be over and above ?

Comment: Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: Put one inside of another?

Comment: Ok I added more detail

Comment: Do you need to have same height for two divs or the `.main` should float right to `.extend`?

Comment: @code-jaff, the same height for both divs based on the height of `.main` which isn't fixed. `.extend' should float left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you could do a simple hack like,

```
.container {
    display:table-row;
}
.extended {
    display: table-cell;
    background: green;
    width: 150px;
}
.main {
    display:table-cell;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/5whdc/3/)

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

i guess your`.wrapper` is taking 100% width or your browser screen.and `.main` or `.extend` creating problem for you and that is contained in .container.so thats why i edited `.container` below.if iys make your container like below

```
.container{
     overflow:hidden;//very importantant to fulfill your criteria
     width:500px;//i gues you want have a fixed width of your container
     margin:3px;//if you want to
     word-break:break-all;//if you use fixed width for your container,because you are writing text with width 100% inside the container

}
```

**EDIT:** according to your edit if you want to add.extend below .main the your divs will be

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="main"></dive>
     <div class="extended">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

now your css should be:

```
.main {
   width: 100%;
   //doont use height it will take automatic height
}
.extended {
   background: green;
   width: 150px;
   float: left;
   height: 100%;
   margin-top:40px;//create distance from main here,its better option
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are trying to make two columns of same height. Take a look here [HTML/CSS: Making two floating divs the same height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1205159/html-css-making-two-floating-divs-the-same-height) for some advice. The issue is explained here http://alistapart.com/article/fauxcolumns