# Mimic the table cell behaviour with divs: middle vertically aligned text, and the content in one cell that enlarges the height of both cells

Tags: html, css, html-table, cell

I would like to translate this table html code
http://cssdesk.com/u7r7h
in div + css code.

The idea is to have A text of any length, in a container of a minimum height, but that can enlarge itself in height, if needed. When the text enlarges the green div, the yellow div should enlarge in height along with it. The text in the green and yellow divs is always vertical - middle- aligned

It's so easy to achieve this with a table with a pair of cell, but so hard with divs and CSS for me.

I'm spending hours on it, without finding a solution.
Any idea?

Comment: Have you looked at CSS's display: table? http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/getting_your_di

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

HTML:

```
<div id="container">

    <div id="left-col">
      <p>column 1</p>
      <p>some other random text</p>
    </div>

    <div id="right-col">
      <p>column 2</p>
    </div>

  </div>
```

CSS:

```
#container {
      overflow: hidden;
      width: 100%;
    }
    #left-col {
      float: left;
      width: 50%;
      background-color: green;
      padding-bottom: 500em;
      margin-bottom: -500em;
    }
    #right-col {
      float: left;
      width: 50%;
      margin-right: -1px; /* Thank you IE */
      border-left: 1px solid black;
      background-color: yellow;
      padding-bottom: 500em;
      margin-bottom: -500em;
    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/R7Y49/1/

it has already been answered [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1205159/html-css-making-two-floating-divs-the-same-height)

Comment: Hi, thx for your help! I have a problem: the text should be middle-alligned in the divs. Should be at the center, vertically, in both the divs...

Comment: There are several examples out there. http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/vertical-centering/

Comment: Mmm.. nothing has the ability to adjust the height, and both, have the content centered in vertical from what i have seen...