# equal height of two columns

Tags: html, css

I have 2 columns. One have dynamic height.

I want to second column adjust to same height as column one.

### Question:

How to set height to div `two` to have same height as div `one` ?

*Note: looking for css/html solution (**NO JS**)*

### JSFIDDLE:

[JsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/mMcqA/)

### HTML:

```
<div class="one"></div>
<div class="two"></div>
<div style="clear: both;">
```

### CSS:

```
.one {height: 300px; float: left; width: 70%;}
.two {height: 50px; float: left; width: 30%;}
```

Comment: With css and html alone you can't

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTML/CSS: Making two floating divs the same height](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1205159/html-css-making-two-floating-divs-the-same-height)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use this modified css and html **[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/lvtrvd/dGGQT/)**

HTML

```
<div class="wraper">
    <div class="one"></div>
    <div class="two"></div>
    <div style="clear: both;">
</div>
```

CSS

```
body{
    width:100%;
}
.wraper{
    display:table;
    width:100%;
}
.one {height: 300px; background: #f00; display:table-cell; width: 70%;}
.two {height: 50px; background: #000;  display:table-cell; width: 30%;}
```

Comment: +1, Yes, this is how to do it. You just beat me to it. (I was about to post [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/mMcqA/3/)

Comment: I think you have been achieve what you want.