# Css sidebar height 100% in foundation

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

I'm using the grid system in the [foundation framework](http://foundation.zurb.com), with a sidebar and content area. I want to extend the height of the sidebar navigation based on the content of main part (`small-10`):

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="small-2 columns">
        <div id="side-nav">
            <ul>
                ...
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="small-10 columns">
        @RenderBody()
    </div>
</div>
```

I've tried:

```
#side-nav
    {
        height:100%;
        background:#f0f0f0;
    }
```

Comment: Try this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1205159/html-css-making-two-floating-divs-the-same-height

Answer (score 0):

If you want two columns to be the same height, that is one case where I would still use `<table>`'s

Answer (score 0):

set css

```
   #side-nav
   {
    display:block;
   }
```

Comment: can u give fiddle or ur site link

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/R3e8P/  row ans small-2 and 10 are foundation frameworks classes

Comment: do u want like this  http://jsfiddle.net/sebin/52KLV/ ?    increase  previe window width