# Issue with Div inside a div and page going to bottom

Tags: css, html

I have gone thru the site and searched for the last two hours and am trying to get a wordpress site to work correctly. Everything is working except the white box that holds the content will not go to the bottom no matter what I try. I have tried all the options here but I think it may be that I do not understand enough about css or the divs are all messed up from the template. Can someone please help out with what I have crossed. My page is located at http://craftedimages.com/AA/aae-events/ and you will see the white box on the right that does not extend down. I got this template and have been modifying it of which there were already lots of problems. Thanks for your time ahead of time.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1205159/html-css-making-two-floating-divs-the-same-height and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/90178/make-a-div-fill-the-height-of-the-remaining-screen-space. Also search for liquid column layout and faux columns. There are many different approaches depending on what exact effect you want.

Answer (score -1):

Try adding

```
#page{
height:1035px;
}
```

..to the css - the sidebar is this height and although it is auto that is the given height

Hope this helps

Comment: That will only help with the size of your monitor. Setting height by pixels in this case is not what you should do.

Comment: The sidebar is 1035px height regardless of monitor size. and the #page div wants to be the same height as this so giving the #page a class of "home_page" and in the css adding .home_page{height:1035px;} should work

Comment: you are mistaken, it is only 1009px on mine. I'm sure it is different on different sized monitors.

Answer (score -1):

Using chrome inspect element. I can see that your `<div id="wrapper"></div>` has the style

```
height:auto;
```

set it to

```
height:100%;
```

That should fix it. Only do that for this page. The other pages are set to auto because it forms to their content. This page doesn't have enough content to reach the bottom like the rest of the pages.

Comment: Just adding height: 100% to the wrapper will not make the 'content' panel the same height as the sidebar.