# How to automatically increase height of a div, as the height of another div increases?

Tags: html, height, auto-increment

Here is what i want...

```
<div style="width:1000px;">

  <div style="float:left; width:300px; height:auto;">    </div>
  <div style="float:right; width:700px; height:auto;">    </div>

</div>
```

I want that, if height of second DIV increases, height of third DIV should also increase automatically...

In short,
(second DIV height = third DIV height)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1205159/html-css-making-two-floating-divs-the-same-height

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **[JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript)** to get an element height and then use this value to set other element height, as you can see here using **[jQuery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery)**:

```
var height = $(".div1").height();
```

And, if your first `div` height changes with the window resize or something like this, you can use an `EventListener` to call the function that will modify the `.div2` based in the first div's height:

```
window.addEventListener('resize', function(event){
    $(".div2").css({"height":height});
});
```

You can even apply a CSS `transition` to the height property to animate the height change.

[**JSFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/TiagoMarinho/BA8Vr/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Use [this](http://meetselva.github.io/attrchange/) plugin and write a function so when one div's attribute (which in our case is Height) changes, your function updates the other one's Height!

Answer (score 1):

There are a few different methods for solving this problem. See here: http://css-tricks.com/fluid-width-equal-height-columns/

Answer (score 0):

Thankyou everyone!
The easiest solution is to use TABLE instead of DIV (wherever this issue rises)...