# How to make floated columns stretch to fill container vertically?

Tags: css

> I need to support >= IE9

Click <kbd>Run code snippet...</kbd> to see my two columns

```css
main {
  background-color: limegreen;
}

.row {
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

section {
  float: left;
  margin: 0 2%;
  width: 46%;
  background-color: palegreen;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="row">
    <section>
      <p>Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue. Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum.</p>
      <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
    </section>
    <section>
      <p>Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna. Integer posuere erat a ante venenatis dapibus posuere velit aliquet. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna. Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Maecenas faucibus mollis interdum.</p>
      <p>Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit. Nullam quis risus eget urna mollis ornare vel eu leo. Aenean lacinia bibendum nulla sed consectetur. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue. Aenean eu leo quam. Pellentesque ornare sem lacinia quam venenatis vestibulum. Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros.</p>
    </section>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <section>
      <p>Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna. Integer posuere erat a ante venenatis dapibus posuere velit aliquet. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna. Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Maecenas faucibus mollis interdum.</p>
      <p>Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit. Nullam quis risus eget urna mollis ornare vel eu leo. Aenean lacinia bibendum nulla sed consectetur. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue. Aenean eu leo quam. Pellentesque ornare sem lacinia quam venenatis vestibulum. Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros.</p>
    </section>
    <section>
      <p>Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue. Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum.</p>
      <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
    </section>
  </div>
<main>
```

I would like the each `<section>` to have a matching vertical height. I'm not sure how to do this using CSS.

Comment: `display: table/table-cell` is one solution. Second is to use `flexbox`. But if you need to use `floats`, [have you tried this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1205159/html-css-making-two-floating-divs-the-same-height)?

Comment: Also, height: in pixels is working but not with percentage.

Comment: I don't have to use floats. I'm just a CSS oldschooler. `table/table-cell` look promising as I need to support `IE >= 9`.

Comment: @naomik then [display:table/table-cell](http://jsfiddle.net/u73q92va/) is a nice solution.

Comment: @naomik is it all sorted out?

Comment: @Pangloss I suppose. The `table/table-cell` has it's own rigidness when it comes to incorporating a responsive layout, but I'll just have to work around it. I'm probably being overly nitpicky about the design anyway. I've been down this rathole before, trying to do overly complicated things, I mean. I'm probably better off sticking to basics.

Comment: @naomik I'm going to suggest a sort of complete answer shortly, see if it can give you more ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can stick with `float` if you want, by using CSS pseudo elements + position tricks for the equal height background color, see the following snippet and comments inline.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vxtwxdhr/2/)

```css
main {
    background-color: limegreen;
}
.row {
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid red;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    position: relative;
}
section {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 2%;
    width: 46%;
    background-color: palegreen;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1; /* top of the pseudo elements */
}
.row:before, .row:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    background: palegreen;
    width: 46%; /* same as section width */
    height: 100%;
}
.row:before {
    left: 2%; /* left margin */
}
.row:after {
    left: 52%; /* 2% + 46% + 2% + 2% */
}
```

```html
<main>
    <div class="row">
        <section>
            <p>Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue. Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum.</p>
            <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
        </section>
        <section>
            <p>Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna. Integer posuere erat a ante venenatis dapibus posuere velit aliquet. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna. Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Maecenas faucibus mollis interdum.</p>
            <p>Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit. Nullam quis risus eget urna mollis ornare vel eu leo. Aenean lacinia bibendum nulla sed consectetur. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue. Aenean eu leo quam. Pellentesque ornare sem lacinia quam venenatis vestibulum. Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros.</p>
        </section>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <section>
            <p>Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna. Integer posuere erat a ante venenatis dapibus posuere velit aliquet. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna. Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Maecenas faucibus mollis interdum.</p>
            <p>Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit. Nullam quis risus eget urna mollis ornare vel eu leo. Aenean lacinia bibendum nulla sed consectetur. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue. Aenean eu leo quam. Pellentesque ornare sem lacinia quam venenatis vestibulum. Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros.</p>
        </section>
        <section>
            <p>Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue. Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum.</p>
            <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
        </section>
    </div>
</main>
```

Another approach would be CSS `table` + `table-row` + `table-cell`, like others already suggested in the comments above. I'm adding it here, plus the extra `border-collapse` + `border-spacing` features, for drawing the gaps. When comes to responsiveness or mobile style, you can simple reset the relevant `display:table*` properties back to `display:block` or so.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gptsn6dm/2/)

```css
main {
    background-color: limegreen;
    display: table;
    border-collapse: separate;
    table-layout: fixed;
    border-spacing: 20px;
    width: 100%;
}
.row {
    display: table-row;
}
section {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: top;
    background: palegreen;
}
```

```html
<main>
    <div class="row">
        <section>
            <p>Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue. Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum.</p>
            <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
        </section>
        <section>
            <p>Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna. Integer posuere erat a ante venenatis dapibus posuere velit aliquet. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna. Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Maecenas faucibus mollis interdum.</p>
            <p>Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit. Nullam quis risus eget urna mollis ornare vel eu leo. Aenean lacinia bibendum nulla sed consectetur. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue. Aenean eu leo quam. Pellentesque ornare sem lacinia quam venenatis vestibulum. Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros.</p>
        </section>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <section>
            <p>Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna. Integer posuere erat a ante venenatis dapibus posuere velit aliquet. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna. Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Maecenas faucibus mollis interdum.</p>
            <p>Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit. Nullam quis risus eget urna mollis ornare vel eu leo. Aenean lacinia bibendum nulla sed consectetur. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue. Aenean eu leo quam. Pellentesque ornare sem lacinia quam venenatis vestibulum. Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros.</p>
        </section>
        <section>
            <p>Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue. Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum.</p>
            <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
        </section>
    </div>
</main>
```

The outputs between the two solutions are slightly different, but mostly adjustable. One more thing on HTML syntax - the last `<main>` should be the closing `</main>`.

**EDIT**

Added `table-layout:fixed` for easy equal width of the columns, no matter how many of them.

Comment: You clearly have a mastery of CSS. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @naomik Also a note, `<main>` element has some problems in lte IE11 - [reference](http://caniuse.com/#feat=html5semantic), and [an article about that](http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2015/Jan/12/main-HTML5-Tag-not-working-in-Internet-Explorer-91011).

Comment: @naomik fixed a typo for `border-collapse` value, also added `table-layout` feature, but you may or may not need it.

Answer (score 1):

just add `display: flex;` to container

```css
main {
  background-color: limegreen;
}

.row {
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
   display: flex;
}

section {
  margin: 0 2%;
  width: 46%;
  background-color: palegreen;
 

}
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="row">
    <section>
      <p>Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue. Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum.</p>
      <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
    </section>
    <section>
      <p>Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna. Integer posuere erat a ante venenatis dapibus posuere velit aliquet. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna. Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Maecenas faucibus mollis interdum.</p>
      <p>Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit. Nullam quis risus eget urna mollis ornare vel eu leo. Aenean lacinia bibendum nulla sed consectetur. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue. Aenean eu leo quam. Pellentesque ornare sem lacinia quam venenatis vestibulum. Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros.</p>
    </section>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <section>
      <p>Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna. Integer posuere erat a ante venenatis dapibus posuere velit aliquet. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna. Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Maecenas faucibus mollis interdum.</p>
      <p>Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit. Nullam quis risus eget urna mollis ornare vel eu leo. Aenean lacinia bibendum nulla sed consectetur. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue. Aenean eu leo quam. Pellentesque ornare sem lacinia quam venenatis vestibulum. Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros.</p>
    </section>
    <section>
      <p>Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue. Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum.</p>
      <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
    </section>
  </div>
<main>
```

If you want IE 9 support you can use [Match Height JS](http://brm.io/jquery-match-height-demo/)

Comment: I should've mentioned I need to support IE >= 9. Sorry.

Comment: I didn't know about the power of flex. Thanks. It's nice and I wish I could use it. +1