# Maintain 100% height of columns with dynamic content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In a two column layout, where one column is static and the other has generated content, how can both be maintained to be 100% the height of the wrapper?

https://jsfiddle.net/t1h4vngv/1/

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="col left">
    Static stuff
  </div>
  <div class="col right">
    Dynamic Stuff
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
html,
body,
.wrapper,
.col {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.col {
  float: left;
}

.left {
  background: lightblue;
}

.right {
  background: lightgreen;
}

.thing {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background: beige;
  border: 2px solid grey;
}
```

**JS**

```
var el = '<div class="thing">Hi</div>'
var $right = $('.right')
for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
  var $el = $(el);
  $right.append($el)
}
```

Comment: Have a look here: https://css-tricks.com/fluid-width-equal-height-columns/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flexbox can do that:

```js
var el = '<div class="thing">Hi</div>'
var $right = $('.right')
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  var $el = $(el);
  $right.append($el)
}
```

```css
html,
body,
.wrapper,
.col {
  min-height: 100%; /* note min-height */
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
}

.col {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.left {
  background: lightblue;
}

.right {
  background: lightgreen;
}
.thing{
  width:200px;
  height:100px;
  background:beige;
  border:2px solid grey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="col left">
    Static stuff
  </div>
  <div class="col right">
    Dynamic Stuff
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Damn, you beat me to it. I was just scrapping up a codepen haha. I'll upvote your answer for using flex ;)

Answer (score 0):

The problem here comes from the float. In fact you want to set the same height to two floated elements. Have a look on that ticket [HTML/CSS: Making two floating divs the same height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1205159/html-css-making-two-floating-divs-the-same-height)

Try to add some content in the right column, you'll see that it works. Hope it helps ;)