# Create img with vertical align middle in column of row in Bootstrap

Tags: html, css

```css
body {
 font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
 background: #0d0d0d;
}
body a {
 color: #fff;
}
body a:hover {
 color: #fff;
}
@media (min-width: 1500px) {
 .container{
  width: 1470px !important;
 }
}
nav {
 background: #1c1c1c !important;
 margin-bottom: 50px;
}
.toper {
 padding: 100px;
 background: #071931;
 color: #fff;
}
.main {
 background: #121212;
 border-radius: 2px;
 margin-top: -60px;
 color: #fff;
 padding: 15px 15px;
}
.container-first {
 background: #2a2a2a;
 margin: 0px 0px 15px 0px;
 padding: 5px;
}
.breadcrumb {
 margin: 0px;
 background: #2a2a2a;
}
.container-first-right {
 padding-top: 2px;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 768px)
{
 .container-first-right {
  float: none !important;
 }
}
.welcome {
 background: #444;
 border-radius: 3px;
 padding: 0px !important;
 margin-bottom: 15px;
}
.welcome-header
{
 padding: 15px 20px 15px 20px;
 background: #2d2d2d;
 border-radius: 3px;
 margin: 10px;
 box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 15px 0px #000;
}
.welcome-text
{
 padding: 10px;
 margin: 10px;
 color: #ccc;
}
.welcome-action {
 padding: 15px 0px 15px 20px;
 background: #4d4d4d;
 color: #ccc;
 letter-spacing: 5px;
 border-radius: 3px;
}
.bluer {
 padding: 15px;
 background: #046092;
 border-radius: 3px;
 font-weight: 500;
}
.section-bluer
{
 padding: 0px;
 margin-top: 15px;
}
.section-first
{
 background: #1c1c1c;
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 10px;
}
.section-picture
{
 padding: 5px;
 height: 100%;
 text-align: center;
}
.section-picture > img
{
 border: 1px solid #016d9b;
 vertical-align: middle;
}
.section-this p
{
 color: #ccc;
 font-size: 12px;
}
.section-this h4 a
{
 color: #87b8d7;
 font-weight: 500;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pl">
 <head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta charset="utf-8"><link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu:400,500" rel="stylesheet">
 </head>
 <body>
  <main class="container main">
   <div class="container-fluid bluer">
    <a href="#">Najnowszy news: #98 Tygodnik MPC News - O grach MMORPG słów kilka!</a>
   </div>
<div clas="container-fluid row">
    <div class="col-sm-8 section-bluer">
     <div class="bluer">
      Projekty MPCforum.pl
     </div>
     <div class="row section-first">
      <div class="col-sm-1 section-picture">
       <img src="fb.png" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-8 section-this">
       <h4><a href="#">League of Legends</a></h4>
       <p>Ćwicz swój refleks, opanuj percepcję i zostań przywódcą grupy! Stań się prawdziwym bohaterem świata League of Legends i doskonal swoje umiejętności taktyczne.</p>
       <hr>
       <a href="#">Metin2 - Publikacje Serwerów, </a><a href="#">Metin2 - Publikacje Serwerów, </a><a href="#">Metin2 - Publikacje Serwerów, </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3 section-last-post">
       asdasd
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
     
    </div>
   </div>
   </div>
  </main>
 </body>
</html>
```

It is something like this:

[image]

And as you can see I want this image to have vertical align middle.

I tried to add it with css, tried setting this column height not 100% but 100px or more. Make this img display inline-block etc....

And nothing works good. And have no Idea what to do now with it and make this works.

Comment: The columns are floated so `height: 100%` won't work. You could use `line-height: 130px` if the adjacent content won't change much...

Comment: It can't be line-height. It has to align-vertically to height, not by setting it manualy. There will be many rows like that with different height @ovokuro

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep your current `HTML` structure you could add the image as a pseudoelement and center it vertically. It's not a pretty solution, and you'll need to use media queries to undo this. Best to view the snippet full screen.

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
  background: #0d0d0d;
}

body a {
  color: #fff;
}

body a:hover {
  color: #fff;
}

@media (min-width: 1500px) {
  .container {
    width: 1470px !important;
  }
}

nav {
  background: #1c1c1c !important;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.toper {
  padding: 100px;
  background: #071931;
  color: #fff;
}

.main {
  background: #121212;
  border-radius: 2px;
  margin-top: -60px;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 15px 15px;
}

.container-first {
  background: #2a2a2a;
  margin: 0px 0px 15px 0px;
  padding: 5px;
}

.breadcrumb {
  margin: 0px;
  background: #2a2a2a;
}

.container-first-right {
  padding-top: 2px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .container-first-right {
    float: none !important;
  }
}

.welcome {
  background: #444;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 0px !important;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.welcome-header {
  padding: 15px 20px 15px 20px;
  background: #2d2d2d;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin: 10px;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 15px 0px #000;
}

.welcome-text {
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
  color: #ccc;
}

.welcome-action {
  padding: 15px 0px 15px 20px;
  background: #4d4d4d;
  color: #ccc;
  letter-spacing: 5px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.bluer {
  padding: 15px;
  background: #046092;
  border-radius: 3px;
  font-weight: 500;
}

.section-bluer {
  padding: 0px;
  margin-top: 15px;
}

.section-first {
  background: #1c1c1c;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.section-picture {
  padding: 5px;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.section-picture>img {
  border: 1px solid #016d9b;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.section-this p {
  color: #ccc;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.section-this h4 a {
  color: #87b8d7;
  font-weight: 500;
}

.section-first {
  position: relative;
}

.section-first::before {
  position: absolute;
  display: block !important;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  content: url(https://placehold.it/40x40) !important;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pl">

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu:400,500" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <main class="container main">
    <div class="container-fluid bluer">
      <a href="#">Najnowszy news: #98 Tygodnik MPC News - O grach MMORPG słów kilka!</a>
    </div>
    <div clas="container-fluid row">
      <div class="col-sm-8 section-bluer">
        <div class="bluer">
          Projekty MPCforum.pl
        </div>
        <div class="row section-first">
          <div class="col-sm-1 section-picture">
            
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-8 section-this">
            <h4><a href="#">League of Legends</a></h4>
            <p>Ćwicz swój refleks, opanuj percepcję i zostań przywódcą grupy! Stań się prawdziwym bohaterem świata League of Legends i doskonal swoje umiejętności taktyczne.</p>
            <hr>
            <a href="#">Metin2 - Publikacje Serwerów, </a><a href="#">Metin2 - Publikacje Serwerów, </a><a href="#">Metin2 - Publikacje Serwerów, </a>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-3 section-last-post">
            asdasd
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4">

      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
  </main>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: my current html structure is bad?

Comment: No, but it's not doing what you want. Bootstrap floats columns, so you will have to use a workaround in your case.

Answer (score 1):

The column/div containing the image is currently only the height of the image because the div is floated, as [ovokuro](/users/8091553/krystian-polska) mentioned. To make it match the height of your other columns, you can first adjust the height of the column/div (col-sm-1) then manipulate the image's positioning inside it.

If a simple situation where all your rows will have a fixed height, you could try setting col-sm-1 to the needed row height (e.g. 100px) and then adjusting the image's position with margin/padding/etc. as needed.

If your rows will vary in height, here are a few approaches that have worked well:

- [HTML/CSS: Making two floating divs the same height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1205159/html-css-making-two-floating-divs-the-same-height)
- https://css-tricks.com/fluid-width-equal-height-columns/

Hope one of these works out!